# not able to filter view data in ,net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to filter my "Index" view data on selected index change of "Language" dropdown. i have written a jquery code to postback on selected index change of language dropdown which will call "Index" action method for filtering data on the basis of Language selected.The action method is returning filtered data to the view but still the output coming is the dafault data(showing all the results for all languages. Below is my code. what i am doing wrong here?

My Action method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string langId)
    {
        List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
        if (langId != null)
        {
            movies = db.Movies.Where(p => p.Language == langId).ToList();
        }
        else
            movies = db.Movies.ToList<Movie>();
        ViewBag.Languages = GetLanguages();
        return View(movies);
    }
```

My view:

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#drpLanguage").change(function () {
   debugger;
   var drpVal = this.value;
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Movies")' ,
    data: { 'langId': $('#drpLanguage').val() },
    success: function (result) { 
     
    },
    error: function (ts) {
     debugger;
     alert(ts.responseText)
    }
   });
  // e.preventDefault();
  });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
@model IEnumerable<MVCMovies.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div> Language:@Html.DropDownList("drpLanguage", new SelectList(ViewBag.Languages, Model), new { id = "drpLanguage" })</div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MovieName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Language)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MovieName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Language)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MovieId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MovieId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MovieId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: "The action method is returning filtered data to the view but still the output coming is the dafault data" This doesn't make much sense. Either it returns filtered data, or it returns all the data. Which is it? The most obvious thing I can see with your code is that you don't do anything with the response from the ajax. Also, your ajax is going to get a _whole page_ of HTML back (i.e. a whole view including `<html>` tags and everything). That's really not what you want from ajax - you don't want to insert a whole page inside another page. Your ajax endpoint should return a PartialView or JSON

Comment: Your returning a view back to the client, but you never do anything with it. You need to update the DOM in the `success` callback. But you need to call a separate method, and return just a partial view, otherwise you may as well just make a GET to the Index() method